# Can't register new appplication Oauth

Tags: office-365

I have an app hosted in Azure that queries a SP list.
I was able to to create a clientId and client Secret and connect to SP fine.

But now that I'm trying to do the same for a different site:
Going to sites`/mynewsite/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx`
generate keys and enter the right data. I get to a confirmation page but then when I go to:

```
sites/mynewsite/_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx
```

I can't find the app registration that I just made.

I've done this before to a different site but, for some reason, now I can't even register new apps on that one. I can still get my old app registration under:

```
sites/oldsite/_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx
```

and use it's clientId and secret do access the list. But I can't create new ones.

Do you know the reason for this? Is it office365 configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure if it is the exact same problem I was facing, but I was also suddenly not being able to create new apps with my existing App Domain. After a lot of trial and error I ended up putting in the App Domain text box my App Domain but I included the port.

*Domain*sharepoint.com -> *Domain*sharepoint.com:443

After that I was finally able to create / register my new app.

Hope this helps.